# Spring & Elasticsearch: Update multiple documents on the basis of particular field and without ID

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using:

1. Elasticsearch:        6.4.3
2. Spring Boot:          2.1.9.RELEASE
3. Spring Elasticsearch: 6.4.3

I have a index in ES:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "logi_info_index": {
      "properties": {
        "area": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "createdBy": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "createdDate": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "logiCode": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "esId": {
          "type": "keyword" -> @Id for ES
        },
        "geoPoint": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        },
        "isActive": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "latitude": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "longitude": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "storeAddress": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "storeName": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "updatedBy": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "updatedDate": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in this index there could be around 50K documents.

For some business logic, I need to update all the documents which satisfy a specific condition: `isActive=0`.

Example:

We have documents, which have `isActive as 0 or 1`.

- Delete all documents which have `isActive = 1` 
  [=> This is possible with `DeleteQuery` (deleteAll) <=]
- Since now we have only `isActive = 0` we want to update remaining documents with `isActive = 1`.

I have *following questions*:

- How can I **update all** the documents with a value for specific field, **WITHOUT using Id** (as I did in delete)?
- Is this **at all possible?**
- If it is possible, I want to use Spring's capability to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Spring Data Elasticsearch (which I assume you use, as this question is tagged for this).

Even in "plain" Elasticsearch this is not easy, the only possiblity there is to use the [Update By Query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docs-update-by-query.html) in combination with a script (I just adapted the doc example, did not try it):

```
POST logi_info_index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.isActive=1",
    "lang": "painless"
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: I did it using UpdateByQuery and Java client!

Comment: Is there any major performance drawback with these kind of bulk updates in Elasticsearch?

Comment: I never had the use case for such an update. But as this will be executed straight on the cluster it will be definitely faster than first retrieving the ids and then issuing update requests for them. And 50K or records is not that much. I'd recommend to create a sample installation/index with dummy data and try it out.

Comment: Sure. Thanks! 50K may increase exponentially. Anyway, I'll try out on dummy data as you rightly pointed. I'll also update my Java code on this answer in coming days.

Comment: @AdiV How did your update go on the dummy data for 50K records? Did you notice any impact on the performance?

Comment: @CiscoJavaHadoop Update works fine for 50K records by using the Java Client. No major performance impact seen with 50k records.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using ES java client and UpdateByQuery:

```
public void updateAll() {
    assert elasticsearchOperations != null;
    UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateByQuery = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE
        .newRequestBuilder(elasticsearchOperations.getClient());
    updateByQuery.source(((Document) CommonUtility
        .getDoc(LogiEntity.class, Document.class)).indexName())
        .filter(query("isActive", AppConstants.TEMPORARY_ACTIVE))
        .script(script());
    BulkByScrollResponse response = updateByQuery.get();
    log.debug("process update: {}. Total updated records: {}",
        response.getStatus(), response.getUpdated());
  }

private Script script() {
    String updateCode =
        "if (ctx._source.isActive == '" + AppConstants.TEMPORARY_ACTIVE + "') "
            + "{"
            + "ctx._source.isActive = '" + AppConstants.ACTIVE + "';"
            + "}";
    return new Script(ScriptType.INLINE, "painless", updateCode,
        Collections.emptyMap());
  }

private QueryBuilder query(String fieldName, String value) {
    return QueryBuilders.matchQuery(fieldName, value);
  }
```

- I tested it with **1.5M** records in Elasticsearch, trying to **update 1.2M** records and takes about close to **1.5 minutes**.
- Since this is a batch application, for now, above is acceptable for me.
- Although, I'm sure it can further be improved using bulk updating and batching of requests for update.